# Ubuntu 11.04 low graphics mode - won't boot at all

Tags: ubuntu, boot

A dialogue now comes up when I turn my computer on (its the only thing in the middle of the screen), saying it is in low graphics mode because it could not detect my settings. I tried the option of staying in low graphics mode for this session but it would hang on boot.

When I pressed escape It said "fail" next to apache2 config file (no file exists) and a couple of other things I cant remember. EDIT: there was also a "fail" next to gnome display manager if that helps at all?

The only changes I have made in the last day or so were to the LAMP sever which I could not get working and I changed my sound settings because I got new speakers (Logitech z5500). I don't know if they would have any affect on things.

---

The only option that did work from the low graphics dialogue was exit to command line login (or something similar I cant quite remember what it was called). I could login to my user although I don't know any commands to sort this out so that didn't help me.

---

If all else fails I will reinstall 11.04 but I managed to get to the Internet so if you guys have any suggestions before I resort to that please let me know.

Comment: Please add more detail to this question.  The dialog appears where?  Where did you set this? Note that you very rarely need to re-install to solve problems like this, so just expand on the detail a bit more and people will get you up and running

Comment: @paul The dialogue appears when I turn on my computer and when I try any of the options it says it needs to restart the display. It then just stays on the startup screen (ubuntu logo and a few dots underneath). I left it for quite a while and nothing happened.

Comment: Did you try any of the other options there? Restart X often works for me.

Comment: Yes I tried restart x and the same thing happened (Nothing happened). It just showed the ubuntu logo again.

Comment: Could this be a driver problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite tell from the description whether this other question is relevant but it might be worth a try:

[Ubuntu 11.04 fresh install - "Input signal out of range" or "Mode not supported..."](https://superuser.com/questions/340148/ubuntu-11-04-fresh-install-input-signal-out-of-range-or-mode-not-supported)